# Compact and natural way to write matrix product of vectors in Numpy

Tags: numpy, vector, matrix-multiplication

In scientific computing I often want to do vector multiplications like

**a** x **b**^T

with **a** and **b** being row vectors and **b**^T is the transpose of the vector. So if **a** and **b** are of shape [n, 1] and [m, 1], the resulting matrix has shape [n, m]

**Is there a good and straight forward way to write this multiplication in numpy?**

*Example:*

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6,7])
```

Adding axes manually works:

```
a[:,np.newaxis] @ b[np.newaxis,:]
```

and gives the correct result:

```
[[ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8 10 12 14]
 [12 15 18 21]]
```

Einstein notation would be another way, but still somewhat weird.

```
np.einsum('a,b->ab', a,b)
```

What I was hoping to work, *but doesn't work*, is the following:

```
a @ b.T
```

Any other approaches to do this?

Comment: .. `a[:,None]*b`?

Comment: Yes, that works! Nice and short!

Comment: You can also use `a.reshape((-1, a.size())`. The -1 will self-adjust the new dimension.

Comment: [outer product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html): `np.outer(a, b)`

Comment: @Brenlla thats nice as well

Comment: It helps to be sure that you understand there is a difference between shape (n, 1) and (n,).  In the example, your  `a` and `b` have shape (3,) and (4,), respectively.  If you create or reshape them to have shapes (3, 1) and (4, 1), then `a @ b.T` will work.

Comment: To an experienced `numpy` user, the `*` elementwise multiplication is most natural.  With broadcasting it can do anything `outer` can.  `np.dot` was the standard for sum-of-product multiplications (matrix product).  `@` (and np.matmul) generalizes `dot`.  For 2d arrays `dot` and `matmul` are the same.  They differ when dealing with 3d arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB matrix multiplication is the norm, using `*`.  Element wise multiplication uses `.*` operator.  Also matrices are atleast 2d.

In `numpy`, elementwise multiplication uses `*`.  Matrix multiplication is done with `np.dot` (or its method), and more recently with the `@` operator (`np.matmul`).  `numpy` adds broadcasting, which gives the elementwise multiplication a lot more expresiveness.

With your 2 examples arrays, of shape (3,) and (4,) the options of making a (3,4) `outer product` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product include:

```
np.outer(a,b)     

np.einsum('i,j->ij, a, b)  # matching einstein index notation

a[:,None] * b       # the most idiomatic numpy expression
```

This last works because of broadcasting.  `a[:, None]`, like `a.reshape(-1,1)` turns the (3,) array into a (3,1).  `b[None, :]` turns a (4,) into (1,4).  But broadcasting can perform this upgrade automatically (and unambiguously).

```
(3,1) * (4,) => (3,1) * (1,4) => (3,4)
```

Broadcasting does not work with `np.dot`.  So we need

```
a[:, None].dot(b[None, :])   #  (3,1) dot with (1,4)
```

The key with `dot` is that the last dim of `a` pairs with the 2nd to last of `b`.  (`np.dot` also works with 2 matching 1d arrays, performing the conventional vector dot product).

`@` (`matmul`) introduces an operator that works like `dot`, at least in the 2d with 2d case.  With higher dimensional arrays they work differently.

```
a[:,None].dot(b[None,:])
np.dot(a[:,None], b[None,:])
a[:,None] @ b[None,:]
a[:,None] @ b[:,None].T
```

and the `reshape` equivalents all create the desired (3,4) array.

`np.tensordot` can handle other dimensions combinations, but it works by reshaping and transposing the inputs, so in the end it can pass them to `dot`.  It then transforms the result back into desired shape.

Quick time tests show that `np.dot` versions tend to be fastest - because they delegate the action to fast BLAS like libraries.  For the other versions, the delegation is a bit more indirect, or they use `numpy's` own compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, multiple solutions were proposed, which I summarize here:

- `np.outer(a,b)`, which basically reformulates this multiplicaten as a set problem (thanks to [Brenlla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6091318/brenlla))
- `a[:,np.newaxis]*b` (thanks to [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar))
- `a.reshape((-1,1)) @ b.reshape((-1,1)).T` or just as well
  `a.reshape((-1,1)) @ b.reshape((1,-1))` . It is a bit long, but
  shows that these numpy matrix operations actually need matrices as
  inputs, not only vectors (thanks to [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) and
  [heltonbiker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401828/heltonbiker))

For completeness, my previous already working examples:

- `a[:,np.newaxis] @ b[np.newaxis,:]`
- `np.einsum('a,b->ab', a,b)`

*Remark:* To reduce the number of characters even more, one can use `None` instead of `np.newaxis`.